# Retrieve data on a django templates

Tags: django, django-models

I am having trouble to understand the principles of retrieving data in template. I understand very well how to do it from the Shell. But I always block on how to do it using class based view. 
I have a simple view :

```
class ProjectDetailView(generic.DetailView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    model = Project
    template_name = 'project_details.html'
```

so in my template I easily retrieve data from the model Project like 
{{project.name}} or {{project.team_id}}

But If I want I would like to show in my project detail data from other models, how can I do it ? 
Let assume I would like to show a list of all team members ?

here are my models:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '')
    team_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank=True, null=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name="members")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name


class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True)
    project_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey('registration.MyUser', blank=True, null=True)
    candidat_answers = models.ManyToManyField('survey.response')
```

Comment: You must be passing a particular object of model project to your context right? Same way you can do for Team model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you don't do queries in templates; you do them in the view, whether it's a class or function based view.

In this particular case though, since the data is linked via relationships, you can follow those relationships in the template:

```
Team: {{ project.team_id.name }}
Members: 
{% for member in project.team_id.members.all %}
    {{ member.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Data that isn't linked in that way can be added to the context by overriding the `get_context_data` method in your view.

Comment: Hi daniel ok so if the models are link I just follow the relationship and if it is not linked I used the get_context_data to extract it and put it in context. OK Got it thx you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should add extra data to your context, like this:

```
class ProjectDetailView(generic.DetailView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'project_details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(ProjectDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the team members
        context['members'] = self.get_object().team_id.members.all()
        return context
```

Then, in your template you will be able to show them like this:

```
{% for member in members %}
    {{ member.name }}   # or any other attribute
{% endfor %}
```

Hope it helps!